# What is a lorestone for?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

I found a lorestone and am under the impression that I got some xp off of activating it. It also said that I can get more benefits when I find a set of lorestones.

What type of benefits do I get from lorestones? Is this another must catch them all for min-maxers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you touch a lorestone, you'll be told a bit of lore and be given a small amount of XP. There is also an achievement for activating all of the lorestones. The game keeps track of which ones you've activated under the Status section:

[image]

Each found set will also grant you a permanent bonus. A small check mark will appear next to the lorestone set once you've found all of them to show that you've gotten that reward.

For example, in the picture above, I found all the lorestones in the Castle Windmere area so I received a permanent 2% increase to critical hit.

Comment: And completing a set will give you a permanent bonus to boot!

Comment: @RavenDreamer Thanks! I added that to my answer and showed an example in my picture

Comment: There's also a small XP bonus per stone, and a bit of "story" that plays when you touch it

Comment: @agent86 definitely. In favor of a more comprehensive answer, I added that in, thanks :)